# unescape not working from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript

```
Why my onclick function cannot unescape single quotes.
```

This is the format:
= '   "   ' '   ' '  "   '
The single quotes inside the double quotes are messing up my code.
Here's my sample code:

```
  <?php
     $myfunction = 'onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false,'<img
     src=icon.gif>');return false;"'
     ?>
```

I tried:

using \'

---------------------------- and also

assigning a variable like this

$ggg  = "('mceInsertContent',false,'');return false;";
.'

Answer (score 1):

of course the single quotes will mess up your code as from the PHP's viewpoint it isn't executable code, it is just a string, which should properly escaped by you using \ backslash like this:

```
 <?php
 $myfunction = 'onclick="tinyMCE.execCommand(\'mceInsertContent\',false,\'<img
 src=icon.gif>\');return false;"'
 ?>
```